# Redirecting after all functions finished

Tags: javascript, express, parse-platform

I am using the Parse hosting and Cloud Code functions.

I have a button that runs a function and then redirects to the same page to refresh it after the function has been called. The cloud function that is being called by the button then calls a number of different functions from there, including a httpRequest. From what I can see, the page is refreshing after the first function has been called, not the subsequent functions and httpRequests being called later. The data on the loaded page is still displaying old data, and has to be refreshed manually to see the updated data.

Here is the code the button is triggering:

```
  // User Control Panel -- Logic
  app.post('/panel', function(req, res) {
  var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
  if (currentUser) {
    currentUser.fetch().then(function(fetchedUser){
      var username = fetchedUser.getUsername();
      if (fetchedUser.get("timeRemaining") < 10) {
        res.redirect("/panel");
      } else if (fetchedUser.get("isRunning") == false){
        Parse.Cloud.run("dockerManager", {username: username}) // Ignoring the rest of the code, this is where the cloud function is called.
        res.redirect("/panel");
      } else {
        res.redirect("/panel");
      }
    }, function(error){
    });
  } else {
    res.redirect('/panel');
  }
});
```

This is the cloud function that is running:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("dockerManager", function(request, response) {
var username = request.params.username;
var override = request.params.override;
var containerID = request.params.containerID;

//other irrelevant code here    

} else {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  query.equalTo("username", username);
  query.first(function(user) {
    if (user.get("dockerID") == undefined) {
      Parse.Cloud.run("createDockerContainer", {username: username});
      response.success("[Docker Manager] Created Docker Container for username: " + username + " with Docker ID: " + user.get("dockerID"));
    } else if (user.get("isRunning") == true) {
      Parse.Cloud.run("stopDockerContainer", {username: username});
      response.success("[Docker Manager] Stopped Docker Container for username: " + username + " with Docker ID: " + user.get("dockerID"));
    } else if (user.get("isRunning") == false) {
      if (user.get("timeRemaining") >= 10){
        Parse.Cloud.run("startDockerContainer", {username: username});
        response.success("[Docker Manager] Started Docker Container for username: " + username + " with Docker ID: " + user.get("dockerID"));
      } else {
        response.error("noTime");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

});

Each of the functions this is calling send a httpReqest to another server, as shown below:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("stopDockerContainer", function(request, response) {
  var username = request.params.username;

    //irrelevant code

    containerID = user.get("dockerID");
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://[redacted address]/containers/" + containerID + "/stop",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      success: function(httpResponse) {
        console.log("[Docker Stopper] Stopped Docker container for user: " + username + " with ID: " + containerID);
        user.set("isRunning", false);
        user.save();
        response.success(true);
      },
      error: function(httpResponse) {
        console.log("[Docker Stopper][CRITICAL] Error stopping docker container for username:" + username);
        console.log("Request failed with response code " + httpResponse.status);
        response.error(false);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: without code it will be hard to help

Comment: The answer in the abstract is that you need to keep track of when all your async operations are done and then you can redirect.  But, without seeing your code, we cannot get more specific than that so your question will probably need to get closed for lack of detail.

Comment: Added all the neccesary code to see what is being called. Sometimes multiple httpRequests are called.